# split list by delimiter in Kotlin

Tags: list, kotlin

I have a below list

```
val list = listOf("o=one", "t=two", "t=two", "f=four", "o=one", "t=two", "s=seven", "o=one")
```

I wanna split it into list of the list contains `[["o=one", "t=two", "t=two", "f=four"],["o=one", "t=two", "s=seven"],["o=one"]]`

Actually I want to group list by "o=" delimiter and the list will always have at least one "0=" value. How could I achieve this in Kotlin without creating mutable var keyword because of my code should be in the functional style?

I have tried with group() and groupBy{} methods but couldn't get the expected result.

Comment: I had to read this a couple of times to understand (-1), but I _think_ I understand now. Isn't _"s=seven"_ missing in your second sublist? You are not really splitting by a delimiter in the traditional sense, so that might be a poor choice of wording. I.e., what should the output be if the list does not start with "o=.."? And the usual, what have you tried/where are you stuck?

Comment: @StevenJeuris Edited my Question. I could achieve this by using mutable variables but I have to do this without any mutable temp values. I couldn't figure out this.

Comment: _"what should the output be if the list does not start with "o=.."?"_ Any input that is invalid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not cover all edge cases, and there might be better ways of doing it, but given that your requirements are not fully clear and extremely contrived, this should get you started either way. From here on out you can polish it yourself.

```
// Identifies indices of all "o=" elements in the list.
val splitAt = list
    .withIndex()
    .filter { it.value.startsWith( "o=" ) }
    .map { it.index }

// Create sublists.
val split = splitAt
    .windowed( 2, step = 1, partialWindows = true )
    .map {
        list.subList(
            it[0],
            if (it.count() == 1) it[0] + 1 else it[1]
        )
    }
```